# JWT Token always says it's unauthorised

Tags: json, authentication, authorization, token, jwt

To set the token, I'm using:

```
var token = jwt.sign({user: user.id}, "secretToken");
res.json({token: token});
```

Then to check, I use:

```
app.use(jwt({ secret: 'secretToken', credentialsRequired: false}).unless({path: ['/authenticate']}));
```

The version I'm using:

```
"jsonwebtoken": "^5.4.1",
"express-jwt": "^3.3.0",
```

Token is being created correctly, but authorising isn't. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.